# How do I force columns in a Grid to be equally spaced?

Tags: notebooks, grid-layouts

Suppose that I have this table `tab`, which I display using `Grid`.  Is it possible to force the columns to be equally spaced?  All columns should be the same width *and* no data should be discarded/hidden from view.

```
tab = {{"aaaa", "b"}, {"1", SpanFromLeft}, {"2", SpanFromLeft}, {"3", SpanFromLeft}};
Grid[tab, Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {1, 2} -> True}}]
```

[image: gridcolumn]

Comment: You don't have to edit just to say you take that back... you can actually take that back by editing it out ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Grid[tab, Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {1, 2} -> True}}, ItemSize -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So it seems like just adding `ItemSize -> All` does the trick.  Thanks!